# Android - read internal data

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I'm trying to make app, and I need to save string, just like TinyDB in AppInventor. So, I found there http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal that what  I'm looking for is saving data to internal storage, but I don't know how to read it. They say:

To read a file from internal storage:

1. Call openFileInput() and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
2. Read bytes from the file with read().
3. Then close the stream with close()

But I don't know how, my code never works. So I googled how to read from internal storage, and no code worked. Can you please tell me, how to read text from internal storage? :)

This is the code:

```
    EditText tagbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String tag = tagbox.toString();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();


    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput( tag );
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String data = br.readLine();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Ok, so I found the solution. The easiest way to store data ,like TinyDB in AppInventor, is using SharedPreferences:**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 Edtior editor = preferences.edit();
```

To store data:

```
editor.putString("key", "value");
```

To read data:

```
String value = preferences.getString("key");
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help you with it - we are not going to write your code though.

Comment: Ok, the code is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. The easiest way to store data ,like TinyDB in AppInventor, is using SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Edtior editor = preferences.edit();
```

To store data:

```
editor.putString("key", "value");
```

To read data:

```
String value = preferences.getString("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        File selectedFile = new File(path + "/" + selectedFromList + ".txt");

         FileInputStream fstream = null;
         ArrayList sal = new ArrayList();
        try {
            fstream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
          String strLine;
          //Read File Line By Line

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
                sal.add(strLine);
              }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          //Close the input stream
          try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How to convert it into a string? I used: String note = sal.toString();  and it crashes, is that convert wrong?

Comment: sal is an array. So you want to determine what entry in the array you want to use.

So you can use sal[0].toString(); or for (int i = 0; i < sal.length(); i++) { String foo = sal[i].toString(); }

Comment: Eclipse gives me an error at sal[0], the error is: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList"